# Make matlab's impoly vertex only moveable in one dimension

Tags: matlab, position, impoly

Hoi Zamme,

I have a question regarding the change of the behaviour of Matlabs impoly function. I want to modify the moving behaviour that the user is only able to move the vertexes along the X axes and the Y position stays the same.

I tried the following:

```
f = 40*membrane(1,40);r = (1:size(f,2))*5;t = (1:size(f,1))/10;

figure;imagesc(t, r, f); axis xy;hold on; 
plot(t, 100*ones(size(t)), 'g');plot(t, 200*ones(size(t)), 'g')

hp = impoly(gca, [1 100; 5, 200]);
addNewPositionCallback(hp,@(p) setPosition(hp, [p(1,1) 100; p(2,1) 200]))
```

But it seems that the new positionCallback is put in front of the original callback function, as the help page to "iptaddcallback" states:

> NOTE ... If a callback is already installed, iptaddcallback replaces
>   that callback function with the iptaddcallback callback processor, and
>   then adds the preexisting callback function to the iptaddcallback
>   list. ...

Is my assumption with the order of Callbacks right and how can I achieve my needs? Or is there a more clever way to get impoly's vertexes move only along the x-axes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Didn't found the reason why adding a new position callback doesn't work. But solved my problem by setting a position constraint.

```
f = 40*membrane(1,40);r = (1:size(f,2))*5;t = (1:size(f,1))/10;

figure;imagesc(t, r, f); axis xy;hold on; 
plot(t, 100*ones(size(t)), 'g');plot(t, 200*ones(size(t)), 'g')

hp = impoly(gca, [1 100; 5, 200]);
setPositionConstraintFcn(hp,@(p) [p(:,1), [100; 200]]) % Now the vertex only move along X-axes
```

BTW: A shame that it' s again so easy...